# Convert the below Tableau calculated field to SQL

Tags: sql, data-analysis, tableau-desktop

I am trying to convert the below Tableau calculated field to SQL:

Calculated field #1:

```
{ FIXED SM, Date, DC:
MIN(
IF svb = 'S' THEN 
    IF sg = 'X8' AND p = 'N' THEN s * 2 
    ELSE  s
    END
END)}
```

Calculated field #2: s is count distinct of serials

How do I write this in SQL?

```
select 
    case 
        when AST = 'S' and sg = 'x8' and p = 'N' 
            then count(distinct s) * 2 
            else count(distinct s) 
    end as CountS
from 
    table name
group by 
    sm, date, dc
```

Comment: To _what_ SQL, what is your database? ... add the related DB tag as information hovering the `sql` tag says to do.

Comment: Do you have exactly one data row given a SM, date and DC? That is, do those three columns uniquely identify a row in your table? If so, then you can simplify your SQL, and don’t need the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

In the outer query, You just need to sum up 1 for each distinct s under normal conditions and 2 for each distinct s under the special condition (svb = 'S' AND sg = 'X8' AND p = 'N'), across what you specified (sm, date, dc)

```
SELECT 
    sm, 
    date, 
    dc,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN svb = 'S' AND sg = 'X8' AND p = 'N' THEN 2 
        ELSE 1 
    END) AS AdjustedCountS
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        sm, 
        date, 
        dc, 
        svb, 
        sg, 
        p, 
        s
    FROM table_name
) AS distinct_values
GROUP BY 
    sm, 
    date, 
    dc
```